# Random array size at the beginning?

Tags: c, arrays, random

I want to make a random sized array everytime program executes at first but compiler yells me

```
"Error  2   error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0"
```

Is there any way that I can randomly choose the `SIZE` by `SIZE = rand() % 100` at the beginning and then intialize the array with `int myarray[SIZE]={0}` ??? or should I everytime initialize it with an exact number at the beginning?

```
int main(void) {
    int i;
    int SIZE=rand()%100;
    int array2[SIZE]={0};

    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)     //fill the array with random numbers
        array2[i]=rand()%100;
    ...
}
```

Comment: You need a compiler that isn't stuck at a standard replaced twice in the meantime. VLAs were added in C99 (but you can't initialise VLAs like `int array2[SIZE] = {0}`).

Comment: The allocation of variables on the stack require that the size be known.  Use the heap (`malloc()`) if you want it dynamically sized.

Comment: I have to quit Visual Studio then

Comment: Why no one posts an answer with a working sample using `malloc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `malloc()` or `calloc()` to do this in C. For example,

```
int SIZE=(rand()%100)+1; // size can be in the range [1 to 100]
int *array2 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*SIZE);
```

But at the same time, the array size can not be anything other than a constant value.

The following two declarations are valid.

```
int a[10];
```

and

```
#define MAX 10
int b[MAX];
```

But you will get an error if you try to declare using the following methods.

```
int x=10;
int a[x];
```

and

```
const int y=10;
int b[y];
```

Comment: One note for this solution: [In C, don't typecast the return from malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Answer (score 2):

You indicated you're using Microsoft's visual studio. MS visual studio is *not* c99 compilant (they cherry pick at best) and one of the missing features is [VLAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

The best you'll be able to do with MS VS is to do this dynamically using [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    int SIZE=rand()%100;
    int *array2=malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));  // allocate space for SIZE ints

    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)     //fill the array with random numbers
        array2[i]=rand()%100;
    free(array2);   // free that memory when you're done.
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to switch compilers, there are other options.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `rand()%100` can and will be 0. If you want a random value 1 <= n <= 100 then you need to use `(rand()%100)+1`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to make your array a pointer and use [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/):

```
int SIZE=(rand()%100) + 1; //range 1 - 100
int *array2 = malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE);
```

Afterwards you can use `array2` much as you would use an array.

Comment: One note for this solution: [In C, don't typecast the return from malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)